# make pretty url with routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to do something to this effect, I believe:

```
map.connect 'show/:company_name/:id',
            :controller => 'companies',
            :action     => 'show'
```

Basically, each time the show action is called, I would like it to take the company_name param and place it into the url as such (show/:company_name/:id)

However, it seems I am using old (rails 2.x routing api) and cannot use map.connect without getting an error. How can I upgrade this?

Is there some way to do this with "match"?

Thanks!

===================

This is the error I see when I try to use map.connect:

```
undefined local variable or method `map' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x103757458>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think your routes lack a "/" symbol in the first line.
Try this:

```
match '/show/:company_name/:id' => 'companies#show'
```

You can check your routes path with command `rake routes`.

--

Besides, the show action is the default RESTful method in Rails. I'll suggest you change a equivalent word, and reserve "show" action for future or other situation.

In Rails convention, you can write `resources :companies`, and the path will be `/companies/:id` using show action.

Some adjustment, in app/models/company.rb

```
def to_param
  self.name
end
```

So your url will look like `http://yourdoamin.com/companies/37signals`.

In app/controllers/companies_controller.rb

```
@company = Company.find_by_name(params[:id])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your goal, try

```
match 'companies/show/:company_name/:id' => 'companies#show'
```

Comment: thank you! for some reason that is not doing it. it is still showing 'show/:id' ... hm

Comment: Yes, Rails 3 changed quite a bit about the routing. "map" is unnecessary. Take a look at http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html#action-dispatch , http://rizwanreza.com/2009/12/20/revamped-routes-in-rails-3 , and http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/